# How to retrieve the values of the row selected using radio button in Struts2?

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2, struts

I have displayed a table using iterator with a radio button for each row, based on the row selected I want perform edit and delete operations by clicking on a button. How do I retrieve all the values in the row selected by clicking edit or delete button?

This is my code:

```
<s:iterator value="List" var="Bean">
        <tr> 
        <td><s:radio theme="simple" name="ID" list="#{'ID':''}"/>

        </td>
        <td ><s:property value="ID"/></td>
        <td ><s:property value="NAME"/></td>
        <td ><s:property value="STATUS"/></td>
        <td ><s:property value="TYPE"/></td>      
 </tr> 

</s:iterator>
```

Using `s:radio` I can retrieve the ID but I want to retrieve all the values in that row selected.

Is there any possible way of setting the bean for only the row selected so I retrieve its value in the action class?

The ID is not unique, so I cannot use it to retrieve the values in the row I select

Comment: Just retrieve it by the given ID from the DB?

Comment: The ID is not its primary key , it has a composite primary key

Comment: composite by what ? Add all the informations by editing your question please

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you don't have edit features, because you're using `<s:property/>` tag that outputs text only.

For editing capabilities, you need an interactive tag, like a `<s:textfield/>`.

Please note that your `List` and `Bean` (and all your attributes) values are non-standard, because they should begin with a lowercase letter (`getList()` -> `list`, `getBean()` -> `bean`). Please refer to JavaBeans standard, and use CamelCase notation.

```
<s:iterator value="list" var="bean" status="ctr">
    <tr> 
        <td> <s:radio name="selectedId" list="#{'id':''}  
                      theme="simple" />                       </td>

        <td> <s:property value="id"/>                         </td>

        <td> <s:textfield name="bean[#ctr.index].name"/>      </td>
        <td> <s:textfield name="bean[#ctr.index].status"/>    </td>
        <td> <s:textfield name="bean[#ctr.index].type"/>      </td>
    </tr> 
</s:iterator>
```

This way you will need on the Action:

```
@Getter @Setter private Long selectedId; 
@Getter @Setter private List<MyObject> list;
```

and you will access the selected element by looping the list, and picking up the record whose `id` field is matching `selectedId`.

You can achieve that automatically by using the iterator `#ctr.index` property instead of the `id`, but the list must be synchronized;

You can achieve that automatically in a really better way by using a `Map` instead of a List, and using `id` as key, and `myObject` as value.

Enjoy

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is that the ID  is not unique

Comment: How do I get the value of the List from one action to another? Do I need to use sessions?